# Vim config for specific filetypes

Tags: vim

I'm struggling with using .vimrc to apply specific configurations based on the filetype.  Following the `autocmd FileType` suggestion [here](http://www.polarhome.com/vim/manual/v57/autocmd.html#autocmd-filetypes), I have attempted to apply a configuration based on filetype.  Here is what I have in my .vimrc:

```
autocmd FileType tex call Tex_config()
  function Tex_config()
    let g:LatexBox_viewer = 'skim'
    let g:LatexBox_latexmk_options = '-pvc'
    let g:tex_flavor = "latex"
    setlocal spell spelllang=en_ca
  endfunction
```

I can call the function Tex_config() with :debug Tex_config: Vim happily spets through the function.  So, everything seems like it should work.

But, when I issue `:set filetype=tex` something strange happens: spell checking turns off.  And when I issue `:set filetype=foo` spell checking turns on.  Just the reverse of what I expect to happen from this configuration snippet!

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Here is the full [vimrc](https://github.com/curiousyogurt/dotvim/blob/master/vimrc) (function at 44-50).  Thanks.

Update: Another part of the puzzle: when I load a TeX file, preferences are read without a problem.  The problem arises on `:set filetype=tex`.

Comment: Note, completely revised answer based on my working .vimrc file instead of crazy speculation :)

Answer (score 1):

After comparing your `.vimrc` with mine it seems the primary difference is that all of my function commands end with a bang like this:

```
function! ExtPrefFunction()
   " Preferences here
endfunction
autocmd Filetype ext call ExtPrefFunction()
```

Honestly I don't know why they are that way, but mine work. Also you do this:

```
if &filetype == "ext"
    " Preferences here
endif
```

...but that only registers when you first open the file for editing, not any time the filetype indicator changes.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I tried using a bang, and putting the `autocmd` line after the function, but it didn't work.  Here's another part of the puzzle: when I load a TeX file, everything works swimmingly.  It appears that it is the `:set filetype=tex` that doesn't pick up the filetype properly.  Any other ideas?

Comment: What does `:set` show as the value for filetype when you load a tex file automatically as opposed to setting the value yourself?

Comment: `:set` shows tex as the filetype, both when I load a tex file automatically, and when I set the filetype value myself.